# performApply does not save at BinaryParsTab class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I browse and select new values at C build -  Settings -  Binary Parsers via
Binary Parser Options as a command.

But these selected values are can not be saved.

At the BinaryParsTab there is a comment. So these BinaryParserPages are can
not be saved at the moment as well ...

```
/**
* @noextend This class is not intended to be subclassed by clients.
*/
public class BinaryParsTab extends AbstractCPropertyTab {
/* Settings from binary parser pages are NOT saved by prior CDT version.
* So existing binary parsers _always_ use default values.
* Moreover, obsolete interface is used while attempting to save.
*
* We have to affect both parsers and pages
* to teach them to save data really.
*
* It will be done in next versions. Currently pages are disabled.
*/
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Explain briefly , also check [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: BinaryParsePage values cannot be saved at all ? Am I wrong ?

Comment: are you developing an application extending cdt ? Or just using the cdt and digging up the source code? Whats your motto?

Comment: the first one, we extend the CDT.